# Let the linear transformation,What conditions must b1, b2, and b3 satisfy for T(x1, x2)

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

i have this equation [image]

but does the question mean what condition to be onto or 1-1?

Comment: It's not really asking either. You know that you will not be able to map to all of $\mathbb{R}^3$. The question is asking what the conditions are on a vector $(b_1,b_2,b_3)$ so that it is in the range of $T$.

Comment: it can be onto if x1-->b1,x2-->b1,x2--->b3,so it may be onto,is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

You have to decide if a system of three equations in two unknowns has solutions.

Use the Rouché-Capelli theorem: there exist solutions iff the ranks of the *incomplete* matrix (3x2) and of the *complete* one (3x3) coincide.

In this case you find that the common rank must be $2$ and then equal to the number of unknowns, so there is only one solution.

Then

- How do you find the condition for $(b_1,b_2,b_3)$ ?
- Is the transformation one-to-one ?
- Is the transformation onto ?

Let me know.

Comment: I 100% it is not onto since 2<3

Comment: Right, try the rest.

Comment: do u think x1 will be free variable?

Comment: No. However you can use an easier approach: solve a subsystem 2x2 and let the solutions satisfy the remaining equation.